# Firebase Event parameters missing in console

Tags: swift, firebase-analytics

Here is my (Swift) code to log a particular event:

```
Analytics.logEvent("Category", parameters: [
    "id": cat.id as NSObject,
    "title": cat.title as NSObject
])
```

The "Category" event shows 296 events in the console image below. But I can't find any information about the `id` or `title` of these events anywhere. What am I missing?

Edit: this is a custom event as defined here in the docs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where does 'Category' come from?  You can't create your own constants.  Use one of those shown at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Constants#/c:FIRParameterNames.h@kFIRParameterItemListName .  Secondly, the event count won't be updated till next day.

Comment: This is a custom event. Edited to show documentation.